# Header image always in the middle of the screen

Tags: html, css

I want to create an header image for my website.

I would like the image is always in the middle would have standing. When someone's browser reduced, the image in the center stand. Now I have an example that this site contains only get there no matter how this is done.

http://aarkcollective.com/

Answer (score 2):

@Leeish has the right idea.

Another way is to use the following css

```
.center_element {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -50px;   /* half of the height of the header */
    margin-left: -150px; /* half of the width of the header*/
}
```

With the HTML:

```
<img class="center_element" src="images/header_image.jpg" width="300" height="100">
```

Comment: This still seems hackish to me. If he has an element with a set width, simply setting the margin to auto should work just fine. I do it all the time. I'm not sure what his issue is.

Comment: also not entirely sure what the issue is; I'm guessing that making the image responsive would work @Leeish

Comment: Their images aren't responsive. They are just using what I assume is a background image and have the size set to `cover`. What that does it makes it stretch the image so it at least covers the div. In their case the height of the div doesn't change as you scale bigger, just the width, so if you go bigger you can actually see the image zoom in. You can't do what they are doing with just an `img` tag. You need a `div` with `background image` and the `background-size` set to cover. With just and `img` tag you can keep it centered but the width and height will scale as the image gets bigger.

Comment: Reading that I realize, saying they aren't responsive sounds dumb as I explain how they are responding to width of page. What I mean is, there is nothing special about the image itself.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, but see my edited answer with fiddle and code. http://jsfiddle.net/P8eDT/

Answer (score 1):

```
div{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: [whatever]%;
}
```

As long as your image/div has a fixed width or percent so it scales, it will stay centered with a left and right margin of `auto.` This is probably a duplicate question so you should probably look around for another answer.

**EDIT**

I am editing my answer based on your comments. I made this fiddle to do what I was talking about. http://jsfiddle.net/P8eDT/ I put two `divs` in it. One with an image and one without so you can see. The inner div is flexible width, set height, and stays centered. The image inside the second one is "responsive" in that it will always match the width of the `div`. As far as I can tell this is exactly what they are doing in your example site you posted.  Posted below is the code for the INNER div (The one that is the image).

```
#inner {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(/path/to/image.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

Please note you will need a javascript fall back for older versions of IE that do not support `background-size:cover`. I've done this before and I just use javascript to measure the width/height and which ever is longer I just set that one.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.. Ok, when I have set the browser window to the full width of my screen, the image will centered in the middle - `#hero img {
 min-height: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto; 
 display: block;
}` but when the browser window is smaller than the image, the image will not centered, the left side of the image stays at the left side and will also not centered - for example check my link... You can see that the image will always be centered in the middle of the browser and the middle of the image.. I like to hear from you

Answer (score 0):

you can use `position:fixed` in your css
say that your header has a class of `.header` and a width and height of 800x50
in your css try:

```
.header{position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%; margin:-25px 0 0 -400px;}
```

**edit** if you do not want it to center vertically `Leeish` has the better solution